# how to use JPQL query to count values from a table & combine with an other table related data?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have two tables X and Y. In Table X (Oracle sql), an unique column(primary key) code along other columns in X table.. code column  may have some records in table Y which have column code_id. I want to get count of rows in table Y for code with code and other columns in table Y

and I have springboot entity called Entity I want to map results to using jpql so I want the query in JPQL:

```
public class Entity  {

    private int id;
    private char code;
    private String name;
//   constructor & setters / getters
}
```

and Y table have entity Counter

```
public class Counter {
        private int codeid;
       }
```

I want to use jpql query equivalent to this Oracle sql query

```
select x.*,
  (select count(*) from Y y where x.code = y.code_id) as theCount
from X x  ORDER BY theCount desc , x.name asc ;
```

Example:

Code "A" has 3 entries, Code "B" has 2 entries and code "C" has 0 entries in table Y.

```
 code   name    count   
    A     name1    3
    B     name2    2
    C     name3    0
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some assumptions because I miss your project code. Hope my example will fit your needs. It is not the same SQL but it is still just 1 statement producing the same type of output.

Primary entity `Code` having collection of `Counter`s:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Code {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_ID")
    private List<Counter> counterList;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Counter {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}
```

Spring Data repository:

```java
public interface CodeRepository extends JpaRepository<Code, Integer> {
    @Query("select c.code, c.name, count(l) as amount from Code c join c.counterList l group by c.code, c.name")
    List<Object[]> getSummary();
}
```

It returns:

```
A, TESTNAME1, 3
B, TESTNAME2, 2
```

In case following is inserted into database:

```sql
INSERT INTO CODE (ID, CODE, NAME) VALUES (1, 'A', 'TESTNAME1');
INSERT INTO COUNTER (ID, CODE_ID) VALUES (123,1);
INSERT INTO COUNTER (ID, CODE_ID) VALUES (124,1);
INSERT INTO COUNTER (ID, CODE_ID) VALUES (125,1);

INSERT INTO CODE (ID, CODE, NAME) VALUES (2, 'B', 'TESTNAME2');
INSERT INTO COUNTER (ID, CODE_ID) VALUES (234,2);
INSERT INTO COUNTER (ID, CODE_ID) VALUES (235,2);
```

This is how the result is produced:

```java
codeRepository.getSummary()
    .forEach(sum -> System.out.println(sum[0] + ", " + sum[1] + ", " + sum[2]));
```